# Como importar todas as variáveis static de uma outra classe?

Tags: java, classes

Tenho duas classes, `A` e `B`. A classe `A` precisa acessar todas as variáveis estáticas existentes em `B`. Como fazer essa importação?

Achei muita coisa com `get`, no entanto não parece ser isso. Sou iniciante e estou perdida.

Comment: teria como você colocar o código que esta tentando fazer? Assim ajuda mais as pessoas a lhe ajudarem.

Comment: Acho que poderias postar seus códigos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

independente se você `instanciar` a class B ou utilizar via `import`...
você só vai conseguir acessar seus atributos se estiverem declarados como ***public static***.

Se você instanciou a class B, provavelmente você se deparou com o seguinte erro!

```
Change visibility of 'variable' to public
Creat getters and setters for 'variable'
```

Se acessar via `Import`, apenas necessita chamar dessa forma:
Ex: `B.Nome` ou `Class.Atributo`

Answer (score 5):

Coloque isso na classe `A`:

```
import static B.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

Para acessar todos as variáveis estáticas existentes em B você deve escrever o seguinte `import`:

```
import static B.*;
```

Assim, a classe A terá acesso a todos os membros declarados como `static` que A pode enxergar. Membros quer dizer "variáveis" e "métodos".

Se desejasse apenas uma variável, poderia fazer algo assim:

```
import static B.VARIAVEL_ESTATICA;
```