# Java Importar todas as classes de outro pacote

Tags: java

Tenho 2 pacotes, gostaria de importar para o pacote B todas as classes do pacote A.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Java - importar todas as variáveis static de uma outra classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217884/java-importar-todas-as-vari%c3%a1veis-static-de-uma-outra-classe)

Comment: Oi Sabrina, seria interessante você detalhar melhor seu problema. Assim fica mais fácil podermos te ajudar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Gostaria de importar para o pacote B todas as classes do pacote A

É impossível importar classes para outro pacote. Isso não existe.

É somente possível importar classes de um pacote para uma classe.

Para importar todas as classes do pacote A para **classe** B, você pode fazer de duas formas: *importação explícita* ou *importação implícita*.

---

### Importação Explícita

A importação explícita é utilizada quando você importa exatamente *aquela* classe de algum pacote. Por exemplo:

```
import br.com.teste.controller.ClienteController;
```

Sendo que `ClienteController` é uma classe.

---

### Importação Implícita

A importação implícita é quando você importa todas as classes de algum pacote para sua classe sem declarar a importação uma por uma.

Entenda: você pode importar todas as classes de um pacote na sua classe usando a importação explícita também. Só que pode acabar sendo um pouco trabalhoso dependendo do tamanho do pacote.

Para realizar uma importação implícita faça assim:

```
import br.com.teste.controller.*;
```

Dessa forma **todas** as classes do pacote `br.com.teste.controller` serão importadas para a sua classe.

---

### Exemplo Concreto

Vamos supor que o pacote `br.com.teste.controller` seja composto pelas classes:

- `ClienteController`
- `UsuarioController`
- `ProdutoController`
- `PedidoController`

**Importação explícita**:

```
import br.com.teste.controller.ClienteController;
import br.com.teste.controller.UsuarioController;
import br.com.teste.controller.ProdutoController;
import br.com.teste.controller.PedidoController;
```

**Importação implícita**:

```
import br.com.teste.controller.*;
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pela resposta c: