# Android Studio. Como instanciar um método com uma view em outra classe

Tags: java, android

tenho um método na *MainActivity2*:

```
public void addfoto(View view) {

// meu código bla bla bla bla

}
```

E quero chamar esse método na *MainActivity*. Estou tentando dessa forma mas fica com erro o código:

```
MainActivity2 m2 = new MainActivity2();
m2.addfoto();
```

Mas não ta dando certo. Como eu faço ?

Comment: Qual é o erro que aparece? Ou não aparece erro nenhum? Não omita nada, qualquer detalhe é importante para conseguir uma resposta adequada

Comment: Você tem que importa a classe *MainActivity2* se não, não ira funcionar. Qualquer dúvida é só ler essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217926/60376).

Comment: Que burrice. Era a importação da classe mesmo como o colega acima falou. Obrigado !!!!

Comment: E se for para chamar OnClickListner  de outra classe? como faço ?

Comment: Isso não é um bom principio, melhor será colocar o código desse click numa classe que ambas as Activities possam chamar, assumindo que é de facto o mesmo